# ElasticSearch.Net NEST BulkInsert no Id in document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'd like to use the NEST .Net library to do bulk inserts to elastic search. But I don't want to store my id in the document.

With a single insert I can use the .Id() function to set the Id when it is not in my Type.

Is there a way to do this with IndexMany function?

Or is it a bad practice to NOT store the id in the document? I don't use the Id other than exact search. Why should I store it twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your own id's using bulk as well:

```
var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(3000, 1000))
    descriptor.Index<Doc>(op => op.Document(new Doc {}).Id(i));

var result = this._client.Bulk(d=>descriptor);
```

If you want to rely on elasticsearch generated ids just don't specify `.Id()` or force it to be null using `.Id(null)`